# tryCatch() does NOT work when used within parallelized ddply

Tags: r, parallel-processing, try-catch, plyr

The following chunk of code works only when ddply is non-parallelized; i.e., `ddply(..., .parallel = FALSE)`. Why doesn't it work when `.parallel=TRUE`? I have a calculation to perform that requires parallelization and ddply is perfect for it, but I can't seem to figure out how to parallelize a function that includes a `tryCatch()` statement using ddply. It is as if ddply disregards the fact that the code is within a `tryCatch()`.

```
# tryCatch in ddply

library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)

theFunc <- function(df){
  m <- df$a
  m <- tryCatch(
    {if(m>1){
      # do something normal
      m+1
    }else{
      # do something that throws an error
      m+"mehwhatever"
    }
    },
    warning=function(war){
      message(war)
      m <- df$a
      return(m)
    },
    error=function(cond) {
      message(cond)
      m <- df$a
      return(m)
    },
    finally={
      print("Does this even work?")
      print(m)
      }
  )
  df$a <- m
  return(df)
}

df <- data.frame(a=1:10)

print(df)
nodes <- detectCores(logical = FALSE)
cl <- makeCluster(nodes)
registerDoParallel(cl)

df <- ddply(.data = df,.variables = c("a"),.fun = function(x){return(theFunc(x))},.parallel = TRUE,.paropts = list(.export=c(as.vector(lsf.str()))))

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
print(df)
```

Comment: Yes - this is a duplicate. Sorry! I looked around for quite a while and didn't come across that one - many apologies. Should I just remove the question?

Comment: Nop you can leave it I think. It's useful sometimes to have different ways to search for an issue. They'll just be redirected if they come across your question.

Answer (score 0):

All of the message() calls need to be removed.